# JS notificationclick event not work in Chrome (MacOS)

Tags: javascript, push-notification

I'm using backend Web Push and all works well using Mozilla, but not in Chrome. Actually all works also in Chrome but notification click event handler.

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  if (event.data) {
    let { title, body, url } = event.data.json()

    this.registration.showNotification(title, {
      body,
      data: {
        url
      },
      requireInteraction: true
    })
  }
})

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  event.notification.close() // Android needs explicit close.

  event.waitUntil(
    clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url)
  )
})
```

So on notification click Firefox opens passed url in new tab, Chrome ain't.

Also i tried setting up "self.notificationclick = function()" but still no luck.

My Chrome is 76.0.3809.132, according to compatible devices from MDN list it should work as well as FF.

Comment: so does the notification trigger the click event? Does it do into the if?

Comment: @epascarello 'push' listener - triggered both in Chrome & FF. 'notificationclick' triggered just only in FF.